# JMeter number of threads (users) variable from CSV file not working

Tags: jmeter

I'm reading different parameters from the CSV file with the "CSV Data Set Config" component.

I added the threadCount column in the CSV. It could have for example the value 100.

Then I use in the "Thread Group" component in the field "Number of Threads (users)" the variable ${threadCount} and nothing happens when I run the report.

There is in the log file:

```
2021-09-29 09:34:19,704 DEBUG o.a.j.e.u.ValueReplacer: About to replace in property of type: class org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.StringProperty: ${threadCount}
2021-09-29 09:34:19,704 DEBUG o.a.j.t.p.AbstractProperty: Not running version, return raw function string
2021-09-29 09:34:19,704 DEBUG o.a.j.e.u.ValueReplacer: Replacement result: ${threadCount}
```

If I add the threadCount variable to the "User Defined Variables" component then the program runs correctly.

Could you please tell where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can configure the number of threads in the Thread Group using CSV Data Set Config because Thread Group is initialized **before** the CSV Data Set Config is processed.

If you want to make the number of threads externally configurable you can define it using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like

```
${__P(threadCount,)}
```

Once done you should be able to define the value in following ways:

1. Via *user.properties* file like:

   ```
   threadCount=100
   ```
2. Via your custom .properties file, the same way but you need to pass this file to JMeter via `-q` command-line argument

   ```
   jmeter -q /path/to/your/custom.properties file
   ```
3. And you can override the value via `-J` command-line argument like:

   ```
   jmeter -JthreadCount=100
   ```

More information:

- [Full list of command-line options](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)